# share Jenkinsfile between developers and DevOps team

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkinsfile, which I want to share with all developers of various projects. So, every project team will use same Jenkinsfile, which is shared by me.

The next thing is, every project team will be able to add custom steps to my Jenkinsfile as per their requirement.

So, after few weeks, If I want to add few more steps to my Jenkinsfile and replicate that across all project Jenkinsfile, how can I make it, without affecting custom steps of all these development teams.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit hard to answer, but mostly sounds like a use case for a [Shared Library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/): stored in a separate repository and loaded (explicitly or implicitly by other Jenkinsfiles/pipelines), this allows you to extract common functionality into own functions.

Depending on your actual change, there is a (too broad) range of possibilities, from having a `deploy()` step that you maintain and others use or really means to supply pieces, i.e. steps executed within the pipeline, and you centrally define the flow around it, e.g. including error handling, notifications etc.

Comment: Yeah, as you said, I can specify extra deploy() step or stage in my pipeline code(i.e which will be in shared library). But, how can developers use that stage or step to specify custom steps from Jenkinsfile in their branch.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean

Comment: Sorry, how developers will supply pieces of code to my deploy() step.